# Image component disappears when using flexbox in Next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm encountering an issue with an image disappearing when I apply the **`flex`** class to its parent container in a React component. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<main className="flex">
    <div className='relative h-[200px] max-w-[200px] bg-red-500 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center'>
        <Image src={image1} alt={"image"} fill style={{ objectFit: "scale-down" }} />
    </div>
</main>
```

As you can see, I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling, and I have a container with a red background (**`bg-red-500`**) that's supposed to hold an image (**`Image`** component). However, as soon as I add the **`flex`** class to the **`main`** element, the image disappears.

I've tried various removing the **`flex`** class and testing the layout without it. In those cases, the image displays as expected. However, when I reintroduce the **`flex`** class, the image disappears again.

Can someone please help me understand why the image is disappearing when I use the **`flex`** class and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Specify Width and Height**: Ensure that the parent container has explicit width and height dimensions set. This will prevent the image from being collapsed due to Flexbox's default behavior.

```
<main className="flex">
<div className='relative flex-shrink-0 h-[200px] w-[200px] bg-red-500 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center'>
    <Image src={image1} alt={"image"} fill style={{ objectFit: "scale-down" }} />
</div>
```

**Set Flex Basis**: Instead of setting explicit width and height, you can set the flex basis of the flex item to control its initial size.

```
<main className="flex">
<div className='relative flex-shrink-0 flex-basis-[200px] max-w-[200px] bg-red-500 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center'>
    <Image src={image1} alt={"image"} fill style={{ objectFit: "scale-down" }} />
</div>
```

**Override Flex Behavio**r: You can override the default behavior of flex items by setting the flex property to none or initial.

```
<main className="flex">
<div className='relative h-[200px] max-w-[200px] bg-red-500 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center' style={{ flex: 'none' }}>
    <Image src={image1} alt={"image"} fill style={{ objectFit: "scale-down" }} />
</div>
```